# Valence: remove a user from section

Tags: desire2learn, valence

So there's [this route](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/enroll.html#post--d2l-api-lp-%28version%29-%28orgUnitId%29-sections-%28sectionId%29-enrollments-) to enroll a user in a section, but there doesn't seem to be the opposite: a route to *unenroll* a student from a section.

In fact, there doesn't seem to be a direct route to unenrolling a user from a section from within the LMS itself. I just watched our administrator "unenroll" a student by switching their role in the section to "no role," which, incidentally, isn't a role available via `/d2l/api/lp/1.4/roles/`.

What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, it definitely seems like that is an oversight in the Valence API. I haven't tried it myself yet, but I wonder if the course offering unenrollment cascades down to the section enrollment also? Naturally that doesn't help solve the problem if you have to unenroll a user from a course offering just to switch their section enrollment within that course offering.

In terms of unenrolling a user from a section within the LMS, this can be accomplished by going into the Section Management within that course offering (Edit Course -> Sections). Then select 'Enrol Users', this will open a table listing the classlist where every section has a column that you can check on/off to enroll/unenroll the user in that specific section (check off more than 1 to enroll in multiple sections).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried un-enrolling the student by [referring to the section's orgUnitId directly](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/enroll.html#delete--d2l-api-lp-(version)-enrollments-users-(userId)-orgUnits-(orgUnitId))? Perhaps you can try explicitly removing the user from the section's org unit ID, and then, either removing the student's enrollment from the course offering org unit id, or re-enrolling them in another section, as appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

I think part of the issue is that you are thinking about this from a front end perspective, and not a back end one. The transaction you are looking to do is actually a [*delete*](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/enroll.html#delete--d2l-api-lp-(version)-enrollments-orgUnits-(orgUnitId)-users-(userId)) and not an enrollment. It sounds bad because we are trained to see anything with the word delete as bad, but from a data standpoint, there's no such thing as enrollments and drops, you have inserts and deletes.